# Chapters without dots in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I've used this code

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
```

to remove the dots and page numbers after the entries in my ToC for all chapters. Is there a way to do this just for an arbitrary chapter?

The following is essentially the code I have.

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright, titlepage,numbers=noenddot, headinclude, %openany openright oneside twoside
                footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty, abstractoff, 
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper,
                ngerman,american
                ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}} 

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}

\index{arte}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}

\end{document}
```

The result is this

[image]

What I want is, for instance, only **Test Chapter Two** with dots after the title.

In particular is there a way to make the dots appear when the chapter has no sections?

Comment: Why exactly do you want this? You'd have to add it inside the `.toc` file it self in order to remove it, and then once more to add it again afterwards. Wouldn't it look odd with a varying design?

Comment: In the work I've done almost every Chapter is immediately followed by a section: the page of the section and of the chapter are the same. So when a chapter has no sections I would like to have at least a page number on the right (also without dots). So you say that is the only way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put the toggles `\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}` and `\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}` when and where you need it.

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright, titlepage,numbers=noenddot, headinclude, %openany openright oneside twoside
                footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty, abstractoff, 
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper,
                ngerman,american
                ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tocloft}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}

\index{arte}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}

\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}} 
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}

\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}} 
\chapter{Test Chapter Three}
\section{Section Three One}
\section{Section Three Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And if for some reason you wanted the page number, but not the dots, for a single entry, try this:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright, titlepage,numbers=noenddot, headinclude, %openany openright oneside twoside
                footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty, abstractoff, 
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper,
                ngerman,american
                ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tocloft}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}

\index{arte}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}

\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\cftdotsep{10000}} 
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\cftdotsep{4.5}} 
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}

\chapter{Test Chapter Three}
\section{Section Three One}
\section{Section Three Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks you so much! :-D